# What is on the other side of a handle?

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic

What is the opposite of a handle? How do you call the thing on the other side of a handle?

For example, if you open a file, you usually get a file handle back, which in many object oriented languages is a reference to a file object. In another example, the handle might refer to a function.

But is there a general term for the "target" of a handle?

Searching for the answer has not yielded a definitive result. Resource seems to be popular, is that the best term?

Comment: Resource seems like a good candidate to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably go with that, I was asking to figure out if there was another word. Referent (see accepted answer) was new to me, but I am not sure if I like the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"referent" is the English word that fits, I think.

Webster's defines it as "the thing that a symbol (such as a word or sign) stands for", and we use the same word for the target of references or pointers.

Wikipedia also uses it in the page on handles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)